# Visit all the pages in pagination using custom crawler

Tags: html, pagination, jsoup, web-crawler

I have built a custom crawler using jsoup. I'm able to scrap all the data from a particular listing page. But for pages that have pagination , how do i get the links from the pagination element. Like for say any retail listing present in amazon, ebay, etc , i'm pass in the URL of the first page of the product listing to jsoup. It works fine. But how do i automate the process of getting the remaining pages links.

I understand that i can get the element by hard coding the class of the pagination. But i'm looking for a generic way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        String url = "http://exampleurl.com/index.php?page=" + i;
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    }
```

Hope this brings some light. That code will loop through ten pages in website with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

If the site annotates its pagination links with [`rel="next"`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en), you can follow those links to retrieve further pages.

Beyond that, there's nothing in the HTML itself that specifies the relationship between pages in the pagination.  You'd have to use heuristics (e.g., links with text containing "next" or a sequence of links with incrementing numbers (1, 2, 3 ... last)).  Obviously, these heuristics would not work for every site and may stop working when a site's design is updated.